# Rewriting facility/severity in rsyslog v7 before shipping off to a remote collector

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, syslogd

I have a machine "A" with a local rsyslogd, and a remote collector machine "B" elsewhere listening with its own syslog daemon and log processing engine. It all works great...except that there is one process on A that logs at local0.notice, which is something that B's engine can't handle.

What I want to do is rewrite local0.notice to local5.info before the event is shipped off to B. Unfortunately I can't change B and I can't change the way the process does it's logging on A. Nor can I upgrade rsyslogd on A from v7.6 to v8 (which appears to have some very useful-looking features, like mmexternal, which might have helped).

I think I must be missing something obvious, I can't be the first person to need this type of feature. Basically it comes down to finding some way of passing through rsyslog twice with a filter in between: once as the process logs, through the filter to change the prio, and then again to forward it on.

What I've tried:

- configuring rsyslog to log local0.notice to a file, and then reading that file with an imfile directive that tags it and sets the new fac/sev, followed by an if statement that looks for the tag and calls an omfwd action. I thought perhaps I could persuade rsyslog to write a file at the right prio and then have rsyslog come back around and naturally pick it up. Sadly, no dice.
- loading an omprog module that calls logger -p local5.info if  syslogfacility-text == 'local0', stopping processing there...and then having another config element check for syslogfacility-text == 'local5' and if so calling an omfwd action. Strangely this works but doesn't squash the original messages, now I just get two sets of logs being forwarded to B, one local0 and one local5.

Are there any solutions out there?

Comment: Would the template solution proposed here: http://lists.adiscon.net/pipermail/rsyslog/2014-April/037333.html be viable in your case?

Comment: Why can't you upgrade to rsyslog 8? **Version 7 is outdated**. It was _actively developed around 2014 and is considered dead by the rsyslog team_. (From rsyslog [v7 documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/).)

Comment: @EsaJokinen, unfortunately not.  Local policy only lets me use the software that is already on the box.  If I could use v8, I would.  Or else I would have replaced it with syslog-ng, which can do this out of the box.

Comment: Note to other readers: for rsyslog 8 use https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/v8.2001.0/plugins/external/messagemod/fac-sever-rewrite/fac-sever-rewrite.py

Answer (score 1):

It's more a hack than a solution, but I was unable to find any "clean" way to solve your issue:

The UDP packet payload for local0.notice messages will always start with a <133> value (16*8 + 5 according to rfc3164), while a local5.info maps to <174> (21*8 + 6).

You can use nfqueue+scapy on A to rewrite all occurences of <133> to <174> while sending the packets on the wire and B will receive and log local5.info messages instead of local0.notice.

All other syslog UDP packets will be unaffected and logged normally.

Simple example : https://byt3bl33d3r.github.io/using-nfqueue-with-python-the-right-way.html

The RFC : https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt

Script for tabular PRI values : http://www.digitalprognosis.com/opensource/scripts/syslog-priorities.py

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with syslog-ng, I believe you can do what you are seeking using it as your primary syslog daemon on "Host A", and forward your manipulated message to "Host B". However, because you need to rewrite "hard-coded" message flags, you'll need to disable syslog-ng's own field parsing, so that you can apply a regular expression to the raw syslog (protocol) message.

You will find Syslog-NG has a very powerful message manipulation approach, in general, by reading https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/chapter-manipulating-messages.html

After reading that, you'll see that, sadly, you will likely need to disable Syslog-NG's own syslog message parsing and work with the raw data, by setting the following option in syslog-ng.conf:

```
flags(no-parse)
```

This may cause problems. For example, you will no longer get multi-line syslog messages as "one message", because syslog-ng needs to parse the message to understand it is a single message.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng

Comment: The question is about rsyslog.